# Getting graphic id in reactiveUtils.watch view popup event

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a problem when using reactiveUtils.watch to monitor the view.popup. I need to catch the graphic id to do further customize action, but I didn't find out any infos just from view.popup object. I use graphicLayer to add graphic, such as following:

```
graphic = new Graphic({ 
    geometry: new geometry.Polygon({ 
        rings: coordinates,
         spatialReference: { 
            wkid: 3826 
        }
    }),
     symbol: { 
        type: "simple-fill",
         color: [255, 0, 0, 0.3], // Red color with 0.3 opacity
         outline: { 
            color: [255, 0, 0], // Red color
             width: 1 
        }
    },
     attributes: { 
        Name: "simple-marker",
         Description: tableHTML
    },
     popupTemplate: popupTemplate
});
graphic.geometry.id = "checking_graphic_1"
```

and the reactiveUtils.watch code snippet is as below:

```
reactiveUtils.watch( () => view.popup.visible,   (visible) => {  ///debugger;
      // console.log("view.popup = ");
      // console.info(view.popup);
     
    if (visible) {  ....
    }  
});
```

And another problem is, at the time, I try to use other method to get the graphic, like this:

```
// Event handler that fires each time an action is clicked.
reactiveUtils.on(
  () => view.popup,
  "trigger-action",
  (event) => {
   console.log("event.action.id =" + event.action.id);
});
```

when I use chrome to debug this, I found reactiveUtils.on is not be called.

Is there any good way to catch popupTemplate reactor's graphic id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to popup graphics by watching `view.popup.selectedFeature`.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
view.when(() => {
  reactiveUtils.watch(
    () => view.popup.selectedFeature,
    (graphic) => {
      if (graphic) {
        console.log('graphic', graphic);
      }
    }
  );
});
```